# Php variables on arithmetic operations adding time

Tags: php, datetime

i cannot multiplicate the simple string in arithmetic operation "*" adding mineutes to variable, testing with integers works fine, any idea. Thanks

```
$minu = intval("2");                                                                
$timestring = "00:02:42";

$futureTime = strtotime($timestring) + (60*2); // works fine adding two minutes
$futureTime = strtotime($timestring) + (60 * $minu); // doesn't work and returns same value

$formatTime = date("H:i:s", $futureTime);

echo $formatTime; /// 00:04:42 /// ok

//// NOW i concatenate and storage in DB like this value triming : "1".000412."000"
//// Operation no ejecute when (60 * $minu) with this output 00:02:42
```

Comment: echoing the right formatted value might help - http://ideone.com/ASpXpw

Comment: echo $formatTime. It gives correct result.

Comment: what is your expected output? both variable return same output link time = 1411603482

Comment: Operation no ejecute when (60 * $minu) with this output 00:02:42, after i need concatenate to formated time in this format "1".$formatTime."000" triming :, the final objetive is 1000442000

Answer (score 1):

Result is correct:

```
   $minu = intval("2");                                                             
   $timestring = "00:02:42";

   $futureTime =  strtotime($timestring) + (60 * $minu);

   $formatTime = date("H:i:s", $futureTime);
   echo $formatTime; // 00:04:42
   echo $futureTime; //1411617882
```

Comment: Now, i concatenate and storage result $formatTime2=date("His",          $futureTime) with this command "1".$formatTime2."000" objetive is 1000442000. But fail when include variable $minu

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be make the same result like my code below: And it make no mistake I think

```
 echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:02:42") + (60 * intval('2')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, make sure the variables are correct ;) [You are echoing the incorrect one]

Personally I would use Carbon.  It will have a you a LOT of headache in the future!
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Carbon Example:

```
$minutes = 2;
$time = '00:02:42'
$carbon = Carbon::parse($time)->addMinutes($minutes);
echo $carbon->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$futureTime =  strtotime($timestring) + (60 * $minu);
$formatTime= DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $futureTime );
```